# @react-three/drei Html element is not bubbling up the scroll event

Tags: react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a `<Html><svg /></Html>` element in my react-three-fiber project. This element is grouped with the camera to keep element in front of the camera. When mouse pointer is on this element scroll i not working for ScrollControl and not scrolling. Is there a way to keep scrolling on the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your HTML elements didn't be in canvas.
You can do the following.
Add props 'fullpage' and 'zIndexRange={[-100, -2]}'

ex: `<Html fullscreen zIndexRange={[-100, -2]}>`

Then you can use your scrolling

Comment: Then, I can use scroll without issue. But I can't see HTML elements behind canvas. how should   I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the answer at discourse threejs, but i could not find it right now, here is the solution for people here.

```
function App() {
    const html = useCallback((element) => {
        if (element) element.parentElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }, []);
    return (
        <Html ref={html} as="div" >
            Hello World
        </Html>
      )
}
```

Comment: This solution can be achieved by adding a declarative style and you can avoid adding ref and useCallback. Just add the style prop to the Html component ```<Html style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }} >...</Html>```